# ASP.NET Application and ASPNETDB.MDF

Tags: asp.net

I've built an ASP.NET application and noticed that my /App_Data folder contains two files: ASPNETDB.MDF and aspnet_log.mdf.  They total about 10MB in size.

I'm handling security via an Oracle database and authentication mode = "Forms".

Why did these files get created?  Is it safe to delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing before you configured the providers you clicked on the manage asp.net application button which may have created these for you.

Comment: If that is the case are they safe to delete?

Comment: Yes it is safe to delete it. I did, and nothing bad happened. All settings for your app is stored in `web.config`.